# When data is larger than 1mb the response of api giving error

Tags: android, web-services, web, response, httpwebresponse

I am getting response on Android devices where it gives error when the response is larger than 1mb . I am using GoDaddy Cpanel Linux hosting. The Error is
`520 : WebServer is returning unknow error`. I checked that postman is still giving the same error.

Comment: then how does it relate to `android` and to programming in general? You have the problem with your server. Probably some limit is set there.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko sorry i guess it is not related to android and my server side uploading limit is 2 gb . Can you help ..

Comment: No for sure. There is some problem with your server, that's all we can help with. Contact your server provider support.

Answer (score 0):

The 520 occours when something unexpected happends like listing connection resets, large headers, and empty or invalid responses as common triggers.

in your case there will be limit in filesize on uploading. check the server codes

Comment: .The uploading size limit is 2 gb .